# I turn the application on android and this application crashes. Why?(Kivy)

Tags: android, python, crash, kivy

Did I write correctly? After the application is turned on, the android device must vibrate, but after the application turns on, it crashes. Why my apps on kivy crashed? Code:

```
from plyer import vibrator
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
from kivy.clock import Clock, mainthread
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout #the UI layout
from kivy.uix.label import Label #a label to show information
class UI(FloatLayout):
    """docstring for UI"""
    def __init__(self):
        super(UI, self).__init__()

        self.lblAcce = Label(text="Vibrate: ") #create a label at the center
        self.add_widget(self.lblAcce) #add the label at the screen
        time = 2
        try:
            vibrator.vibrate(time=time)
            #if you want do disable it, just run: accelerometer.disable()
            Clock.schedule_interval(self.update, 1.0/24) #24 calls per second
        except:
            self.lblAcce.text = "Failed to start vibrate" #error
class Vibrate(App): #our app
    def build(self):
        ui = UI()# create the UI
        return ui #show it

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Vibrate().run() #start our app
```

Comment: self.update method?

Comment: https://kivy.org/docs/guide/android.html#debugging-your-application-on-the-android-platform